# Adding addEventListener witch click to if/else statement

Tags: javascript

I want to create a table with buttons. When one button is clicked, the info box is revealed while the rest are hidden. I want to display one box at a time and not at once. Thank you beforehand!

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.visible { display: flex; }
```

```js
function startInfobox1() {
    console.log("start info1");
    document.querySelector(".button1").addEventListener("click", toggleInfo1);

    document.querySelector(".content-info1").classList.add("hide");
}

function toggleInfo1() {
    var info1 = document.querySelector(".content-info1");
    var info2 = document.querySelector(".content-info2");
    var info3 = document.querySelector(".content-info3");
    var info4 = document.querySelector(".content-info4");
    var info5 = document.querySelector(".content-info5");
    var info6 = document.querySelector(".content-info6");

    if (info1.addEventListener("click") == true) {
        info1.classList.remove = "hide";
        info1.classList.add = "visible";

        info2.classList.add = "hide";
        info3.classList.add = "hide";
        info4.classList.add = "hide";
        info5.classList.add = "hide";
        info6.classList.add = "hide";
    } else {
        info1.classList.remove = "visible";
        info1.classList.add = "hide";

    }
}
```

Comment: _”I'm fairly still new to coding especially JavaScript“_ — Perfect opportunity to read the documentation: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [`DOMTokenList` (the return value of `.classList`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), and guide: [Introduction to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Answer (score 0):

`info1.addEventListener("click")` does not tell you that an element is clicked

`info2.classList.add = "hide";` classList add is a method, not an assignment.

Your code is going to be a lot of copy and paste. You should avoid using copy and paste because it is a pain to maintain. One way around this is creating functions that are reusable. By using data attributes you can simplify loop and determine what to show and hide.

```js
// Find all the buttons and loop over them
document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggles]").forEach(function (btn) {
  // add the event listener to the button
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // grab the data attribute for the button that was clicked
    var selector = btn.dataset.toggles;
    // select the element that selector points to
    var newSelection = document.querySelector(selector);
    // determine if something else was already selected
    var currentSelected = document.querySelector(".info.active");
    if (currentSelected && newSelection !== currentSelected) {
      // if it is, remove it
      currentSelected.classList.remove("active");
    }
    // show or hide the item we just clicked on
    // if you do not want it to be removed, use add instead of toggle
    newSelection.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}

.info.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggles=".info-1">1</button>
<button type="button" data-toggles=".info-2">2</button>
<button type="button" data-toggles=".info-3">3</button>

<div class="info info-1">One</div>
<div class="info info-2">Two</div>
<div class="info info-3">Three</div>
```

Comment: By looping, does that mean that I create a loop or make a variable that includes all the data?

Comment: The loop in my code is the forEach. It is looking over all the buttons and it is adding the events. This is to keep you have copy and pasting the same logic over and over and change a couple of lines over and over.

Comment: In your code you have to do `startInfobox1()`, `startInfobox2()`, `startInfobox3()` What is different? a couple of characters in each method.